# Mobile Website Facebook Login using Facebook App for login details

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, android

Using a web browser e.g. Chrome on Android, if a mobile website requires a user to be logged in to Facebook and they are not, the browser will ask for Login details even though the phone may be logged in to Facebook via the Facebook native App. Is there any way to get details from the Facebook App without the user having to log in again?

Comment: What do you expect as "details " ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to login in website in a browser, using Facebook account from Facebook app - it is impossible, without intermediary application, or service. And even with it, I don't think, that you can get user login data.

Other approach - is try to [launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser) Facebook app from your site, and show site from it, but again, you can't login to it, using app.

Why? Because the app, holds only token data, and nothing more. You can't get other information, like password, or email. Also, the work of browser, that save cookies and the app, that save token is different. You can't connect them together.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly speaking it is not possible using website in browser.

Even it is also not possible if you develop any android app, the reason is that the facebook app will not share any data to any other app (even if it is running on the same device).

I also don't think that launching the facebook app from browser will be feasible for you, as you just want to use the facebook login system and then want the users back on your website (and again facebokk will not send any data to your web or app even if it is launched from your web or app).

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not possible, because we wont link browser and an app.
I developed one android app with facebook login integration.If facebook native app already logged in, now i click my app facebook login button it directly redirect my app to my home page without asking fb username and password.

For me i used **localStorage** in javascript

```
localStorage.setItem("userName", userName);
localStorage.setItem("password", password);

var uname=localStorage.getItem('userName');
var pass=localStorage.getItem('password');
```