# Facebook login in mobile browser via Facebook app

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, facebook-login

I have a Node.js web app with Facebook login (using PassportJS, OAuth 2.0). The login works in the browser (Chrome 50) on desktop.

In the browser on mobile (Android, iOS), the login also works but it asks the user to login to Facebook in their browser, even if they are already logged into their Facebook App.

For the browser on mobile case, is it possible to somehow authenticate the user via the Facebook App (if installed) rather than Facebook in the browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobile Website Facebook Login using Facebook App for login details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17525519)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Native Facebook Login experience via browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20943499)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobile Website Facebook Login using Facebook App for login details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525519/mobile-website-facebook-login-using-facebook-app-for-login-details)

Answer (score 1):

Somwhere here already was answer, that due to facebook policy, now you can only use browser for auth in mobile apps.

I'm not sure about android.
Here answer for iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32621036/5475238

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion that this is impossible. However, the answer you linked to relates to an iOS app, not a web app running the browser.